# Using for loops in R to populate a data frame for binomial distribution

Tags: r

Initialize an empty data frame named my_binom_loops with 18 rows and 2 columns. Name the first column y and the second column pdf_y. Then, using nested loops:

- Iterate over the 18 rows.
- Iterate over the 2 columns
- IF the inner loop is on the first column, add increments of 1 to the y column (so like 0 to 17)
- OTHERWISE, fill column pdf_y using dbinom(y, size = 17, p = 0.83)

I'm not sure how to populate my first column(y) in increments of 1.

```
# Initialize an empty data frame named my_binom_loops with 18 rows and 2 columns 
my_binom_loops <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 18, ncol = 2))

# Name the first column y and the second column pdf_y
colnames(my_binom_loops) <- c("y", "pdf_y") 

# Iterate over the 18 rows
# Iterate over the 2 columns
y <- 0
for(rows in 1:18){
  for(cols in 1:2){
    if(cols == 1){
      y <- y + 1
      my_binom_loops$y <-  
      
    }
    
  }
}

my_binom_loops
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options(scipen=99) #display not scientific notation (optional)
y=0
for(rows in 1:18){
  for(cols in 1:2){
    if(cols == 1){
      my_binom_loops[rows,cols]=y
    } else {
      my_binom_loops[rows,cols]=dbinom(y, 17, .83)
      y=y+1
    }
  }
}
```

Each row has y and P(Y=y) with Y~Binomial(17,.83).

```
my_binom_loops

    y                  pdf_y
1   0 0.00000000000008272403
2   1 0.00000000000686609417
3   2 0.00000000026818156067
4   3 0.00000000654678515741
5   4 0.00000011187300518994
6   5 0.00000142012908941109
7   6 0.00001386714287307294
8   7 0.00010639244910181206
9   8 0.00064930685848900134
10  9 0.00317014525026981667
11 10 0.01238221438928917111
12 11 0.03847094417206962241
13 12 0.09391436371416980733
14 13 0.17635502688407453387
15 14 0.24600785262820473731
16 15 0.24021943256636466013
17 16 0.14660450663976656860
18 17 0.04210440848131703773
```

Comment: sorry, appropriate stats package function as in dbinom(y, size = 17, p = 0.83)